# How to read previous line of a match pattern in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a file with below content:

```
a b c d
a d
e f
a g h i
```

Using Scala, I would like to first find the lines which do not start with "a", then append that current line with the previous line. At the end I expect my output to be like this.

```
a b c d
a d e f
a g h i
```

I am able to read a file line-by-line But could not proceed any further

```
import scala.io.Source

val filename = "fileopen.scala"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
  println(line)
}
```

Any help in achieving this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively easy search-and-replace but it does require the entire file be read into memory.

```
val rslt = util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("fileopen.scala")){
  _.mkString.replaceAll("\n([^a])", " $1")
}
//rslt: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(a b c d
//                                       a d e f
//                                       a g h i
//                                      )
```

---

Scala pre-2.13 version:

```
val file = io.Source.fromFile("fileopen.scala")
val rslt = file.mkString.replaceAll("\n([^a])", " $1")
file.close
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. When I execute the above code, I get this error ```test.scala:3: error: object Using is not a member of package util```

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. Might be a dumb question but, What does $1 signify here?

Comment: `$1` is the 1st capture group in the regex pattern that is the 1st parameter to the `replaceAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses a var Option to buffer the previous line starting with an "a" until another "a" line arrives.  If a series of non-"a" lines arrive they are all joined to the previous "a" line.

```scala
var prev:Option[String] = None

for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {

  if (line.startsWith("a")) {
    prev.map(println)                   // flush previous buffered line
    prev = Some(line)                   // buffer this line
  } else if (prev.isEmpty)
    println(line)                       // no previous "a" line so just print input
  else 
    prev = prev.map(_ + " " + line)     // join this non-"a" line to previous line
}

prev.map(println)                       // print last buffered line if any
```

Answer (score 0):

The following functional code for bigger file.

```scala
import scala.io.Source
val file = Source.fromFile("/var/tmp/fileopen.scala")
file.getLines.foldLeft(None: Option[String]){(pl, line) => 
      if(line startsWith "a") {
         pl foreach println
         Some(line)
      } else {
            pl.map(_.stripLineEnd + " " + line) orElse Some(line)
      }        
} foreach println
file.close
```